# Code Review/Opinion - SQLAlchemy and Repository Design Pattern and Unit Tests

Tags: python, unit-testing, design-patterns, sqlalchemy, orm

I have recently started a python project and I am facing some issues with it and I do not really know anyone I could ask for help.
Basically, right now, I am either facing issues with the design of the code or with creating its unit tests and it would be awesome if someone gave me any pointers. I have a mysql database and I am using SQLAlchemy to map the classes to the tables and to do CRUD operations to the database.
I am using the repository design pattern and when trying to create unit tests for one of my Repository classes (TeamRepository) I understood I was not able to mock the Team class. Would anyone be able to let me know if the way my classes are created does not make sense?
I also do not want to create the table teams inside the teamrepository class as that also seems to break isolation principles.

```
class Team(Base):

__tablename__ = "teams"
__table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}

id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
team_name = Column(String(50), unique=True)

def __repr__(self):
    return "<{0} Id: {1} - Name: {2} ".format(self.__class__.__name__, self.id, self.team_name)
```

```
class TeamRepository(Repository[Team]):

def __init__(self, session):
    self.session = session

def create(self, team) -> Team:
    team_instance = TeamRepository.query(self.session, check_team_name = team.team_name)
    logging.info("Team: {0}".format(team_instance))
    if team_instance == None:
        try:
            self.session.add(team)
            self.session.commit()
            team_with_id = TeamRepository.query(self.session, check_team_name = team.team_name)
            logging.info(f"Team created: {team_with_id}")
            return team_with_id
        except Exception as e:
            raise
    else:
        logging.info("Team already exists in Database")

@log(my_logger=my_logger)
def update(self, **kwargs) -> None:
    return super().update(**kwargs)

def query(session, check_team_name) -> Team:
    query = session.query(Team).filter_by(team_name = check_team_name)
    team = query.first()
    logging.info(f"Team queried: {team}")
    if team != []:
        return team
    else:
        return []

@log(my_logger=my_logger)
def query_all(self) -> list[Team]:
    query = self.session.query(Team)
    teams = query.all()
    logging.info(f"Teams queried: {teams}")
    if teams != []:
        return teams
    else:
        return []

@log(my_logger=my_logger)
def delete(self, team) -> None:
    query = self.session.query(Team).filter_by(team_name = team.team_name)
    output = query.first()
    if output != []:
        try:
            self.session.delete(output)
            self.session.commit()
            logging.info(f"Team deleted: {output}")
        except Exception as e:
            raise
    else:
        logging.info("Team does not exist in Database")

@log(my_logger=my_logger)
def delete_all(self):
    try:
        self.session.query(Team).delete()
        self.session.commit()
        logging.debug("All entries were deleted from the table {0}".format(Team.__tablename__))
    except Exception as e:
        raise
```

So far I have this in the test_teamrepository, but I do not actually understand how I can mock the Team class in these tests:

```
@pytest.fixture
def mocked_team(mocker):
    mocked_team = mocker.patch('core.repositories.team_repository.Team')
    return mocked_team

@pytest.fixture
def team_data():
    return {'id': 1, 'team_name': 'U16'}

@patch('core.repositories.team_repository.Team', return_value=Mock)
def test_create_new_team(mocked_session, team_data, mocked_team):
    ## Arrange
    team_repository = TeamRepository(mocked_session)
    mocked_team.return_value = Mock(id=2, team_name="U18")
    mocked_session.add(Team).values(**team_data)

    ## Act
    team_in_table = team_repository.create(mocked_team)

    ## Assert
    assert team_repository.session.query(mocked_team).filter_by(team_name = "U18").first() is not None
    assert team_in_table is not None
```

Any help is super welcomed :) Thank you so much

Running the unit tests like this, pytest obviously complains "NameError: name 'Team' is not defined" because I still do not understand how to mock the team class or how to make the unit tests not depend on the Team class

Comment: I'm not sure this will fit with Stack Overflow but we can try.  You should try to rephrase your title into a question, for example "How to implement the repository design pattern when using SQLAlchemy?"

Comment: I would probably avoid using commit inside the repository because then if you try to combine other operations then you cannot assume they all commit together.